# Как настроить редирект сервера на angular?

Tags: сервер, angular

У меня сайт написан на Angular. При деплое на сервер, перестали работать страницы, если писать их адрес вручную. Я так понял это из-за того что сервер не находит нужный файл html и выкидывает ошибку.
Как грамотно настроить чтобы сервер делал редирект на файл index.html, а дальше все запросы обрабатывал Angular? Пытался делать через панель управления сервера 301 редирект из /login -> /index.html/login, но он просто открывает домашнюю страницу. Хостинг reg.ru, панель управления ispmanager